# how to activate module avail of a program and then run it by bash script - ubuntu

Tags: drivers, bash

I'm new using ubuntu

I'm using a program, which before executing it I need to do the following steps in the ubuntu terminal:

```
$ module load protein-docking/haddock/2.4
```

and only after that I run the program with the following command:

```
$ haddock2.4
```

I created the following bash file with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
./module load protein-docking/haddock/2.4
./haddock2.4
~
```

**but it's not working,
can someone tell me where i'm going wrong?**

Comment: why are you prepending `./` to the `module` command? is it really a local command (in the current directory) or is it one of your system-wide [environment modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_Modules_(software)) ?

Comment: Why `./` and `~` … remove them … leave just the commands as you run them in the terminal.

Comment: *@Raffa and @steeldriver*
I tried and this information appeared:

`Conda uses environments to load different sets of Python packages
type conda env list to see the environments availible.
Loading protein-docking/haddock/2.4
  Loading requirement: ProFit/3.3 dssp/4.0 freesasa/2.14 haddock-tools/1.0 pales/1.0 python/miniconda2 CNS/1.3-haddock
haddock_run.bash: line 3: haddock2.4: command not found`